# Facebook Web App Authentication Via SmartPhone

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I have created a facebook application using Javascript SDK, now When I am trying to authenticate the application by accessing it via my mobile browser (Samsung Galaxy S II), The permission popup box is not appearing at all.

Do I have to make some more changes to it

Please guide.